# Do Technomancers experience any strange effects from being in UV nodes?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, sr4-matrix

In Unwired(p.171) they talk about the legendary **UV Nodes**.  These nodes are overwhelmingly potent, and have addictive qualities to all users.

There is a technomancer playing in my game who *may* have reason to visit one, I'm curious if there are any references (even in flavor text) that might describe some of these effects to a resonant individual.

The basic rules of UV Nodes (allowing regular skills to be used, etc.) obviously still apply to the technomancer, but what might it feel like?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A resonance realm is described as feeling similar to a UV node for a technomancer. The following is a bit of fluff describing a resonance realm, but I feel like it could also be applied to a UV node:

> There is a certain feeling that every
>   technomancer knows when diving through
>   the Matrix. It's more than the
>   constant buzz of data traffic in the
>   background, it's the feeling that
>   there is something *larger* beyond the
>   curtain of icons and background
>   processes. Or perhaps it's a feeling
>   that there are massive depths lying
>   beneath the surface of the Matrix,
>   unexplored and unseen places from
>   which Resonance seeps into the virtual
>   realm.... On the other side, they
>   discovered unique places, thriving
>   with sprites, lit from within by
>   abundant Resonance that shone as
>   bright as the sun.
>   (Unwired p. 172)

This is an oblique answer, I don't know if there's any more detailed fluff out there. The following is my own interpretation/imaginative filling in the blanks:

My feeling is that each UV node is different, and the feeling you get from it would depend on the sculpting and theme. A UV node feels hyper-real, so it might be a symphony of soft breezes that touch every blade of grass, or a shot of adrenaline like waking up in mid-fall. I think I would give the technomancer a stronger-than-usual impression of the theme; it might be overwhelming. UV nodes cause reality filters to fail, and override the user's iconography with the system. Maybe the technomancer would have a hard time distinguishing between the node sculpting and the real world.

Think of the Matrix, from the movie, as a UV node. To a technomancer, maybe it seems real, but something's just a little "off", "like a splinter in your mind", etc.

Comment: Re-bountying so I can give it to you. :)

Comment: Great answer here! Thanks, was basically exactly the type of oblique fluff I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Since we weren't getting an answer here, I took the liberty of asking the question over on the [Dumpshock forums](http://forums.dumpshock.com/index.php?showtopic=32934). The consensus was that UV nodes would be "addictive" and "intoxicating," but nothing specific beyond that.